# How do I connect to a proxy with rasdial?

Tags: windows, vpn, proxy

So I'm trying to connect to a proxy that requires authentication through rasdial.exe but I think I'm messing up the parameters somehow.

It keeps showing me the "Usage" when I type in the command

```
USAGE:
        rasdial entryname [username [password|*]] [/DOMAIN:domain]
                [/PHONE:phonenumber] [/CALLBACK:callbacknumber]
                [/PHONEBOOK:phonebookfile] [/PREFIXSUFFIX]

        rasdial [entryname] /DISCONNECT

        rasdial

        Please refer to our privacy statement at
        'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=521839'
```

And this is what I type in

```
rasdial VPNServer username password ipaddress:port
```

I have modified it a bit to not show my username and password and the ip and the port.

How do I properly connect to the proxy using rasdial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP address and port belongs into the VPN entry settings. They are not provided on the command line.

Comment: When you say `VPN entry settings`, are you referring to the VPN settings inside Settings > Network & Internet > VPN?

Comment: Exactly. rasdial is nothing more than a command line tool to start preconfigured VPN connections.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for clearing that up! I'm currently trying to setup the VPN connection, connecting to an ip that looks like this 127.0.0.1:1234 (not the actual IP) with a username and password but it just keeps loading saying "Connecting" is this a common issue?

Comment: No way to say without knowing details. But that would be another question.

Comment: Sounds good! Thank you for the help!